# Editing Lines in a Text File Using C#

Tags: c#, text, text-files, editing

I have a slightly different problem in comparison to the other "editing text file" problems. For example, I have the following text file:

```
Cal Test
{
     Feature 0.0 1.0 2.0 7.5
     Feature 0.0 -1.0 2.0 -7.5
     .etc
}
```

Say I have about a hundred `Feature` lines in this text file. Essentially, the numbers represent data points; so the first two numbers represent data point: `(0.0, 1.0)` and the second pair represent the second data point: `(2.0, 7.5)`; which represents a line in another program that takes in the text file.

What I want to do, is rotate each data point 90 degrees counter-clockwise; which means `(a, b)` → `(b, -a)`. I know how I can do this, going through reading line by line and editing the points, I would like to know, is there a more efficient way to swap (a, b) and attach the negative?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the entire feature set per line? So the first one would be (1.0, -0.0, 7.5, -2.0)?

Comment: No amount of micro-optimization will produce a noticeable improvement in performance compared to your suggestion to read each line, parse it and make the changes in a direct and simple manner. If you had a billion lines, or even perhaps a million, there might be a case for some sort of optimization (which would most likely revolve around how you manage file IO and memory).

Comment: @keyboardP Yes, thats right

Answer (score 0):

As previously said, not a big improvement, but

Use ReadLines() to get the list of items, as you are probably doing on a

```
var list = new List<string>(); // or whatever structure you use to keep items in memory

foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(anInFileStr))
{
  var lineArray = line.Split(' ') ;
  list.Add(string.format("{0} {2} {1} {3}", lineArray[0], -int.Parse(lineArray[1]), lineArray[2], lineArray[3]));
}

File.WriteAllLines(anOutFile, list)
```